# Cannot import the sql file to the phpMyAdmin error #1558

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to upload the SQL file to phpMyAdmin. Unfortunately, I get this error:

Error
SQL query: Copy

```
--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Add Blood Inventory Record` ()   
    INSERT INTO `blood inventory`(`Donor Name`, `Donor ID`, `Donor Phone Number`, `Donor Gender`, `Concentration of Plasma`, `Hemoglobin`, `Blood Type`, `Blood Volume`, `Blood Pack ID`, `Storage Staff Name (IN)`, `Storage Staff ID (IN)`, `Storage Staff Name (OUT)`, `Storage Staff ID (OUT)`, `Entry Date`, `Expiry Date`, `Storage Location`, `Storage ID`, `Blood Pack Expired`, `Blood Pack Used`, `Blood Pack Usage Venue`, `Blood Pack Usage Case ID`) 
    VALUES ('[value-1]','[value-2]','[value-3]','[value-4]','[value-5]','[value-6]','[value-7]','[value-8]','[value-9]','[value-10]','[value-11]','[value-12]','[value-13]','[value-14]','[value-15]','[value-16]','[value-17]','[value-18]','[value-19]','[value-20]','[value-21]');
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> #1558 - Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 100108, now running 100424. Please use
> mysql_upgrade to fix this error

I already tried doing mysql_upgrade but it still will not import the file

Comment: Do not use blanks in column names

Comment: Have you done `Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error`?

Comment: I have already tried doing mysql_upgrade but it does not fix this error

Comment: It has already been upgraded to 10.4.21-MariaDB